# Angular pods on Kubernetes restarts randomly

Tags: angular, kubernetes, crash, google-kubernetes-engine

My angular code is deployed on Google Kubernetes Engine. When i check the pods, i see there are a number of restarts. When i check the logs using

```
kubectl get logs <pod> --previous
```

there are few error logs of type:

1. Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')

After that the whole 'main.js' file is logged. Can someone please explain why the pods are restarting.I am using Angular 16.

I checked various blogs but cant seem to find any similar issue.

Comment: Do you use SSR? You have a bug in your code. Add some logging like Sentry.

Comment: Yes we are using SSR. Can some errors cause whole pod to crash or restart. I mean when we are running in local there is no such issue.